# No compiling possible ?!

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, texmaker

I've been using Latex for almost 2,5 years now. Since i installed Windows 10 on my Laptop, TeXmaker wont work. The most common error, that its shows is:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.3.5) 6 MAR 2015 20:54 
entering extended mode

I get this message for this code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\title{Ein Testdokument} 
\author{Otto Normalverbraucher} 
\date{5. Januar 2004} 
\begin{document} 

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents 
\section{Einleitung} 

 Hier kommt die Einleitung. Ihre Überschrift kommt 
 automatisch in das Inhaltsverzeichnis. 

 \subsection{Formeln} 

 \LaTeX{} ist auch ohne Formeln sehr nützlich und 
  einfach zu verwenden. Grafiken, Tabellen, 
  Querverweise aller Art, Literatur- und 
  Stichwortverzeichnis sind kein Problem. 

  Formeln sind etwas schwieriger, dennoch hier ein 
  einfaches Beispiel.  Zwei von Einsteins 
  berühmtesten Formeln lauten: 
  \begin{align} 
  E &= mc^2                                  \\ 
  m &= \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} 
  \end{align} 
  Aber wer keine Formeln schreibt, braucht sich 
  damit auch nicht zu beschäftigen. 
  \end{document}
```

I hope one can help me. Next Projects are incoming....^^

Thanks

Comment: Did you recreate the formats as I told you?

Comment: you have not shown any error message just the normal startup banner (although for a two year old latex)

Comment: FWIW, your test file compiles just fine on a MacBookPro, MacOSX 10.13 "High Sierra", MacTeX2017, pdfTeX `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18`, and LaTeX2e format `<2017-04-15>`. Looks like you should update both pdfTeX and LaTeX2e.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me in the same configuration (windows 10, texmaker, MiKTeK 2.9 64 bit)

Update yours packages with **MiKTeK Update (admin)**

[image]

Your format is a bit old (preloaded format=**pdflatex 2015.3.5**)

So build your format with **MiKTeK Settings (admin)**. Il you compile with latex, choose latex and then build. Il you compile with pdflatex, choose pdflatex and build. And so on ..

[image]

You can alternatively Updates all the formats in one command with **Updates Formats** on the **General** tab

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I tried to update it,the way u showed it on your pic. but a error occurred : 
Sorry, but something went wrong: Windows API error 127: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden. (means the given procedure was not found)
dllName="C:\Program Files\MikTeX2.9\miktex/bin/x64\MiKTeX2009-packagemanager.dll"

Comment: Maybe you have tried to do it when another instance of the Update manager or of the MiKTeX settings was opened. Close everything. You can even restart a  new fresh session or even restart the computer to be sure and  try again.

Comment: nope same error :(

Comment: Then try to use the non admin version of the Update manager (close the other one), and if you have it click Ok to repair

Comment: next error(non admin):
Sorry, but something went wrong:
The executed process did not succeed.
fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe",exitCode="1"

Ohhh gosh :(

Comment: You may try to launch the update through the MiKTeK Settings (admin or user) wiht the Task Menu and then Update Wizard, but normally it will not work either. In your case I would suggest a new fresh install of MiKTeK after removing the first one. I Ve done it some days ago and everything works well.

Comment: You can also make a bug report (with log file and so on) https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues

Answer (score 0):

Surprise Surprise:
Solved it:
I deleted everything that included Miktex and Texmaker and installed Miktex again. Updated it, made sure that there is no other update. Ok. Texmaker installed. Still not working. Looked inside of Texmaker Configuration and in PDFLATEX there was this order:  **-shell-escape=external** which i deleted and surprisingly it works now. I did not had it in the beginning until i compared my config with a friend and added it. Puhhhhhhh Finally it works!!! 
Update - Configuration check!

Comment: Congratulations. You may need the **-shell-escape** (without =external) option when for instance you compile some pdftricks code with pdflatex. But it allows access to command system by tex source when they are compiled (by the `\write18` tex command). So this is  security breach which should not be used permanently just when it is necessary because of the packages you use.